# Paste several images into a bigger one, using conditions and loop (MATLAB)

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing, for-loop

I built a binary chessboard (tab):

[image]

Now I have to put in several pieces (pawns), just like this:

[image]

P_1 and P_2 have the same dimension that each block of the chessboard (301x301 px)
like it follows:

P_1 :

[image]

P_2:

[image]

In another exercise I had to invert the images of row 2, doing this:

```
P1_neg=double(P_1)*-1+255;
P2_neg=double(P_2)*-1+255;
```

I obtain this images:

P1_neg:

[image]

P2_neg

[image]

In the second row I have to paste two kind of pieces: a black pawn with black background (`P_1`), and a black pawn with white background (`P_2`).

Each block of the chessboard has 301x301 pixels, and each piece has the same measurements. I have to use only conditions and loops, but I don't know how paste the pieces there.

So, I know for the second row: when the row (i) it even and the column(j) is odd, I have to paste `P_1`; and when the row is even and the column is also even I have to paste `P_2`.

My code, is the following one, I hope you can help me :)

```
for i=1:8                 % from 1 to 8 because it have 8 blocks 
   for j=1:8
       if mod(i,2)==0 && mod (j,2)~=0
             %paste  P_1 (I don't know how do this)
       elseif mod(i,2)==0 && mod(j,2)==0
             %paste P_2 
       end
   end
end

figure,imshow()   % I don't know if I show the chessboard or I have to save the data in another matrix.
```

I couldn't upload the chessboard with the original resolution, but here it's the code I use

```
tab=zeros(2408);   
  for i=0:7             
     for j=0:7         

       if mod(i,2)~=0 && mod(j,2)~=0                        
        for avanza_fila=(i*301)+1:(i+1)*301                  
            for avanza_columna= (j*301)+1:(j+1)*301          
                tab(avanza_fila,avanza_columna)=255; 
            end
        end 
        elseif mod(i,2)==0 && mod(j,2)==0                   
           for avanza_fila=(i*301)+1:(i+1)*301
               for avanza_columna= (j*301)+1:(j+1)*301          
                tab(avanza_fila,avanza_columna)=255;
               end
           end 
       end
    end
end
figure, imshow(tab)
```

Comment: Actually, you have **four** possible images.  A black pawn on a white background, a black pawn on a black background, a white pawn on a white background and a white pawn on a black background.  However, you can get the last two by inverting the first two images (assuming black and white).  Can you show us the pawn images too? Once we have these, it's very easy to put this onto your chessboard.  You just gotta give me more!

Comment: Also, please post the link somewhere to your **original** chessboard.  The ones you have shown in the links are a reduced size.

Comment: I couldn't upload the image, but I put the code I use to build it

Comment: Put it on dropbox or http://files.com and upload it there.

Comment: [url=http://www.files.com/shared/53f7c05520659/Untitled_01.png][img]http://www.files.com/thumbs/small/53f7c05520659/Untitled_01.png[/img][/url

Comment: That's still low res.  That's ok.  I've created a high resolution version of the board.  I'll write an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to your problem.  I would personally avoid `for` loops, but you said your assignment needs it.  I've created a high resolution version of your board that you can get here:

[image]

This board is 2408 x 2408, as each chess piece is 301 x 301, on an 8 x 8 grid.  You almost have the logic correct.  You just need to figure out how exactly to place the tiles on the board.  I wrote two `for` loops where the first `for` loop uses rows 2 and 7, and the second `for` loop goes through columns 1 to 8.  For either the second or seventh row, we check to see whether the column is even or odd and place the correct chess piece in its corresponding block.  I also converted the board and the images to black and white to get rid of any quantization artifacts, as I saw that in the images you have posted.  Also, I have renamed your images to how they're named in your post, so it'll be up to you to change the relevant names according to your code that you have written.  I have also made a copy of the board in the code so that we don't want to modify the original board called `boardCopy`.  This copy will contain the placed chess pieces in the board.  Without further ado, here's the code:

```
board = imread('boardHigh.png'); %// High-res board
P_1 = im2bw(imread('P_1.png')); %// Load in the pawn pieces
P_2 = im2bw(imread('P_2.png'));
P1_neg = im2bw(imread('P1_neg.png'));
P2_neg = im2bw(imread('P2_neg.png'));
boardCopy = board; %// Make a copy of the board
for row = [2 7]
    for col = 1 : 8
        if row == 2
            if mod(col,2) ~= 0
                boardCopy((row-1)*301 + 1 : row*301, (col-1)*301 + 1 : col*301) = P_2;
            else
                boardCopy((row-1)*301 + 1 : row*301, (col-1)*301 + 1 : col*301) = P_1;
            end
        else
            if mod(col,2) ~= 0
                boardCopy((row-1)*301 + 1 : row*301, (col-1)*301 + 1 : col*301) = P1_neg;
            else
                boardCopy((row-1)*301 + 1 : row*301, (col-1)*301 + 1 : col*301) = P2_neg;
            end
        end
    end
end

figure;
imshow(boardCopy);
```

This is the board I get with the chess pieces:

[image]

Hope this helps and good luck!